# Implement IBM Sterling Connect:Direct in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration, ftp, sftp

I was wondering if is possible to implement IBM Sterling within Marketing Cloud, is any way to integrate any IBM Sterling conector in ours Marketing Cloud servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [Connect:Direct documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/it-possible-use-connectdirect-perform-sftp-transfers-sftp-server), there is no support for any FTP-like protocol within IBM Sterling Connect:Direct, making it unsuitable for providing data to SFMC (as the only supported protocols for file transfers are SFTP/FTPS).  You will need to utilise some sort of middleware, to either connect to the Marketing Cloud APIs or SFTP.